# How to get the linker to produce a map file using Cargo

Tags: linker, rust, rust-cargo

I'm writing a Rust program targeted for an STM32F407 processor using zinc. I'd like to be able to produce a linker map file. I've found that I can put the following in my main.rs and this gives me the desired result:

```
#![feature(link_args)]
#[link_args = "-Wl,-Map=blink_stm32f4.map"]
extern {}
```

However, [the documentation for `link_args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/advanced-linking.html#link-args) suggests not to use this method.

What other methods exist to get the linker to produce a map file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`link-args` is possible to pass to `rustc` via `rustc -C link-args="-Wl,-Map=blink_stm32f4.map" test.rs`.

And there is option of `cargo` `rustflags` in `build` section. See [cargo config](http://doc.crates.io/config.html). It works like this:

```
$ cargo new --bin testbin
$ cd testbin
$ cat .cargo/config 
[build]
rustflags = ["-Clink-args=-Wl,-Map=/tmp/blink_f7.map"]
$ cargo build
```

Also there is `linker` option in `cargo` config. I don't try to pass via
this option `gcc` plus `flags`, only `gcc`, but you can write `gcc` wrapper script like:

```
$ cat my-linker.sh
#!/bin/sh

arm-...-gcc -Wl,-Map=blink_stm32f4.map $@
```

Comment: I tried to add:

    [build]
    rustflags = [ "-Wl,-Map=blink_f7.map" ]

to my Cargo.toml file and I get the following warning

    warning: unused manifest key: build.rustflags

I'm using nightly-2016-05-24 to build. It seems that many of the tips I've found by google searching only work on older versions of rust/cargo.

Comment: I got the my-linker.sh script to work - thanks. That should work under linux and OSX.

I'm building something much bigger than a single file, so I'm not sure how calling rustc directly will help. I need to include zinc and its dependencies at link time. 1 of 3 is still progress though.

Comment: @DaveHylands I updated my answer with description how to use `cargo` config, by the way linker also you can set in `.cargo/config` and you can set it to different value for different architictures.

Comment: Sweet. I got your example to work. Using rustflags = ["-C", "linkargs=...] also works. using rustflags = [ "-C linkargs=...] (i.e. space between -C and linkargs) does not.
I think I've been confusing Cargo.toml and .cargo/config which is why some of my attempts didn't work.

Comment: None of these suggestions address the issue if `.cargo/config` applies to a hierarchy of different crates, because only one name can be given for the map file. Short of adding it to each crate's `Cargo.toml`, is there some way to get a uniquely-named map file for each crate?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add something like this in `.cargo/config`:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-Clink-args=-Wl,-Map=/tmp/app.map"]
```

But I got error:

> rust-lld: error: unknown argument '-Wl,-Map=/tmp/app.map'

According to [this blog](http://ramblingfoo.blogspot.com/2019/06/how-to-generate-usable-map-file-for.html), it worked after I changed it to:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-Clink-args=-Map=/tmp/app.map"]
```

Comment: Arguments like `-Wl,-Map` are for GCC or compatible C compilers, which are sometimes used as linkers. The arguments after each `-Wl` argument are passed to the linker by the C compiler. If `rustc` is using a linker directly, which is the default on most targets, you don't need to `-Wl` since you're not talking to a C compiler intermediary.

Comment: Thanks Mastax for the information. I'm aware that `-Wl,option` is a gcc comand line option to pass options to the linker. I'm not sure in which situation will `rustc` choose C compiler or `rust-lld` as the linker. Maybe the default is changed after a certain version. Or just because I'm using `#![no_std]`.